# auto updates to kernel 5.11.0-25 and 5.11.0-27 fail

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

The system is an old HP with an Nvidia graphics card. The last two kernel updates mentioned in the title have failed to build in the last week.

The problem appears to be with building nvidia-340-340.108 for the kernel.  The make log:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-27-generic'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (    
    \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are 
missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
";  \
echo >&2 ;
```

By hand, I tried the make oldconfig, which failed due to lack of flex.  Downloaded that and then failed do to lack of bison.  Downloaded that and make oldconfig was successful.  Then tried make prepare, which then failed due to a missing
arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c file.  This is as far as I care to go down this rabbit hole.  I am currently booting 5.8.0-63 kernel from advanced grub menu.  I have pinned 5.8.0-63 using

```
sudo apt-mark hold on the image and headers for 5.8.0-63.
```

I would like to remove the pieces of the 5.11 kernels, but what advice I have seen on this is somewhat fuzzy.

Comment: How did you install the Nvidia drivers? Did you use `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`?

Comment: I've never have had to do this before.  To this point, the auto updates have apparently done whatever necessary.  Also, upon refection, I find it a little strange that the auto updates for these kernels are calling gcc at all.

Comment: Nvidia 340 drivers are broken with the 5.11 kernel https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1916640